# jquery datepicker position on scroll triggered by button in fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

After searching for hours and digging through the jQuery UI code I am still at a loss on how to correct my particular situation. I'm developing an app that displays data from a database in a table using PHP and datatables.js. Some of the columns have input fields that are editable for the staff that will be updating data. There are three input fields bound to buttons that display the jQuery datepicker. When selecting a row, clicking the appropriate button for the field needing data, and then selecting a date from the datepicker, the input field(s) is/are populated with the date selected. The buttons bound to the input fields are in a fixed position so they scroll down the page. Once the page has been scrolled by the user the datepicker is positioned far below the user view depending on how far down they have scrolled. Using Chrome's inspector I see the datepicker is appended to the bottom of the document just above the closing body tag which makes it understandable why the datepicker is well out of view, but still exists on the page. How can I keep the jQuery datepicker in position with the fixed buttons as the user scrolls???

I hope I'm clear enough on what I'm trying to do since there's most likely more info than needed here. Screenshots are here if needed...

[Screenshot of original position and after scroll](https://www.dropbox.com/s/19k3jej1n42r538/Screen-Shot-2015-06-15-at-4.05.42-PM.jpg?dl=0)

There will be times when multiple rows need to be updated at the same time using the same date which is the reason for not binding the datepicker to individual input fields. There will eventually be thousands of rows so scrolling will be necessary.

Here's the HTML...

```
<input name="approved-date" type="hidden" id="approved-date" onchange="getApprovedDate()" />
<input name="tobe-paid" type="hidden" id="tobe-paid" onchange="getToBePaid()" />
<input name="paid-date" type="hidden" id="paid-date" onchange="getPaidDate()" />
```

Here's the jQuery used which is very basic to setting up the datepicker...

```
$("#approved-date").datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});

$("#paid-date").datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});

$("#tobe-paid").datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});

$('#approved-date + button').button({
    text: true,
    label: 'Approved Date'
});    

$('#paid-date + button').button({
    text: true,
    label: 'Paid Date'
});

$('#tobe-paid + button').button({
    text: true,
    label: 'Verified Date'
});
```

And finally, the jQuery functions to add the selected date into the input fields of the highlighted rows....

```
function getApprovedDate() {

if($('tr').hasClass('active') && $('#approved-date').val()) {

    $('tr.active td .approved-input').val($('#approved-date').val());

    if($('tr.active td.confirmed').html() == 1) {

        $('tr.active td .claim-amount').val('$70');

    }else if($('tr.active td.confirmed').html() == 0) {

        $('tr.active td .claim-amount').val('$50');

    }

}else {

    $('tr td .approved-input').val("");

}
```

}

function getPaidDate() {

```
if($('tr').hasClass('active') && $('#paid-date').val()) {

    $('tr.active td .paid-input').val($('#paid-date').val());

}else {

    $('tr td .paid-input').val("");

}
```

}

function getToBePaid() {

```
if($('tr').hasClass('active') && $('#tobe-paid').val()) {

    $('tr.active td .tobepaid-input').val($('#tobe-paid').val());

}else {

    $('tr td .tobepaid-input').val("");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

After smacking my head against the desk a few times I solved my own problem and it's so simple. The only thing needed was to set the top position for the .ui-datepicker class in jquery-ui.css as such...

Original CSS...

```
.ui-datepicker {
   width: 17em;
   padding: .2em .2em 0;
   display: none;
}
```

Modified CSS...

```
.ui-datepicker {
   width: 17em;
   padding: .2em .2em 0;
   display: none;
   top: 70px !important;
}
```

For me 70px was the correct position so if anyone comes across this problem just set the top position to whatever you need and make sure to include !important or it will be overridden. Now the datepicker widget displays with the button no matter where you scroll to on the page.